# Bigquery - CREATE A TABLE using json schema file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a empty table in BQ using a json schema file on my desktop but get the following error.

My query:

```
bq mk \
--table \
--description "TEST_FILE_UPLOAD_BQ" \
--label organization:development \
gf-dev-models-204097:VS.TEST_FILE_UPLOAD_BQ \
C:/Users/johnsnow/Desktop/TEST_Upload_file.json
```

ERROR:
/USERS/SALIANV/DESKTOP/TEST_UPLOAD_FILE.JSON is not a valid value

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with windows path. You can try to quote your path

```
bq mk \
--table \
--description "TEST_FILE_UPLOAD_BQ" \
--label organization:development \
gf-dev-models-204097:VS.TEST_FILE_UPLOAD_BQ \
"C:/Users/johnsnow/Desktop/TEST_Upload_file.json"
```

Or use a relative path

Comment: Are you using cmd, powershell, bash? 
Can't you use relative paths?

Answer (score 0):

Try without the ".json" extension: The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#mk-table) says no extension should be provided.